# Primefaces datatable Identify if the current column is of date type

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I am trying to make a common datatable using primefaces.
I want to check if the current column of datatable is of Date type. If it is a Date I want to add DatetimeConverter -

Here is my code -

```
<ui:component>
<p:dataTable id="#{tableId}" value="#{data}" var="row" styleClass="stdTable vertLines fndTable vertLinesRightBorder" 
            style="table-layout:fixed; border-color: #dddddd;">
            <p:columns value="#{tableColumns}" var="column" sortBy="#{row[column.property]}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    #{column.header}
                </f:facet>
                #{row[column.property]}
            </p:columns>
        </p:dataTable>
    </ui:component>
```

I am calling the above xhtml as follows-

```
<ui:include src="table.xhtml">
        <mbcpos:param name="tableId" value="#{me.id}hTabel1" />
        <mbcpos:param name="data" value="#{taskListBean.receivedOwnerTasks}" />
        <mbcpos:param name="tableColumns"
            value="#{me.columns}" />
    </ui:include>
```

Can we identify the column datatype :
e.g., #{row[column.property]} equals Date 
If the column is a date I want to format the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column model should be where you put the data type it holds and other data type presentation related things like masks, currency, alignment etc.

On the page, for each data type (according to your needs), inside the **p:columns**
you should do something like this:

```
<h:outputText rendered="#{column.dateType}" value="#{row[column.property]}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
</h:outputText>
```